# Flutter and Social Sign In (Google) client id key storing approach

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I'm building a *Flutter app (ios/android)* and I want to implement *Google Social Login*.

When I created my Google Cloud OAuth credentials I was provided a ClientId which I'm to use to create the GoogleSignIn object, so it must be used in my flutter app.

Is there a recommended approach to store these types of keys on the flutter app side? I'm not sure what are the security liabilities involved and so I come to you for help.

So far I had no keys on my flutter app and I'm just not sure if exposing (reverse engineering) this Google OAuth Client Id is even a problem.

Comment: As long as you restrict the use of the key in the Google Cloud console, there are no problems with leaks or the form of storage, even if it leaks, only your application will be able to use it.

Comment: This happens because they validate the WHO is querying their API through the app bundle identifier, is that right? I had to register an app bundle identifier when creating the key. I'm not sure if this happens because i'm in a development environment, but I can currently query the google sign in endpoint with the same client id from a different bundle identifier id (other app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

If you want to read more about it here's an article: [Is it safe to expose your Firebase API key to the public?](https://medium.com/@paulbreslin/is-it-safe-to-expose-your-firebase-api-key-to-the-public-7e5bd01e637b)

Comment: Okay so it seems okay to expose it, meaning I can just store it as a variable in my flutter app with no problem of exposing it if someone goes to the trouble of reverse engineering it. That's great, thank you so much David!

Comment: That's what they said in the documentation too. Plus I think even after reverse engineering they wouldn't be able to link your firebase to the re-engineered app

Comment: You can also go through some official flutter open source code to use as a guideline

Comment: I'm not using firebase for auth, I already had mongodb as a database and redis for token  storing/renovation so I decided I was going to implement auth without another database. Going through some flutter open source code sounds like a great idea actually, thanks!